# Create color overlays with swatches from a saved color table

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I created a color table of swatches for my Photoshop project and I would like to be able to access those swatches when applying color overlays. Is this possible without manually entering the RGB values? Thanks!

Comment: Hi punchlabel, welcome to GD.SE! I might not be understanding your question but can't you use the Swatches Panel in Photoshop (Window -> Swatches)? Photoshop CC also has the panel "Libraries" which can also contain swatches and other assets that can be used on other Adobe products as well. So just use the eyedrop tool and select the swatch.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is you creating a Style for each color from your table. You'd just have to click your layer and apply the style (it also comes handy when you want to replicate not just a layer style like color overlay but also more layer styles and layer blend modes in just one click).

Open the Layer Style menu, select overlay, pick your desired color but before you click OK to close the Layer Style menu you'll find the "New Style..." button below the OK one.

There you can name it, and configure the extra bits (include layer effects/inlcude blending options), you will find the new style in your style palette. Repeat it for each color.

You can also make a Style library for them after.
And ready, style, blend and effects replicated in one click.